# List Drives using a WCF Service in Silverlight C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

Trying to get a list of drives from a server side application using a WCF Service and i keep getting an error/ no drives found. Here is my Server side code. Hoping someone could shed some light on this never ending "Access" issues with silverlight!

```
[OperationContract]
    public List<AllDriveInfo> ServerDriveInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            DriveInfo[] ComputerDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            //List<DriveInfo> ComputerDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            //string[] ComputerDrives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
            List<AllDriveInfo> ServerDrives = new List<AllDriveInfo>();

            foreach (DriveInfo drive in ComputerDrives)
            {
                AllDriveInfo NewDrive = new AllDriveInfo();
                NewDrive.DriveLetter = drive.VolumeLabel;
                NewDrive.VolumeName = drive.Name;
                ServerDrives.Add(NewDrive);
            }
            return ServerDrives;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I've recently also tried a different approach by using "InteropServices" with the code stated below. However WCF seems to not have any name space for the AutomationFactory object which is normally the refrence:

`using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation;`

```
[OperationContract]
        public List<AllDriveInfo> ServerDriveInfo()
        {

            dynamic fileSystem = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            dynamic drives = fileSystem.Drives;
            List<AllDriveInfo> Drives = new List<AllDriveInfo>();

            foreach (var drive in drives)
            {
                try
                {
                    Drives.Add(new AllDriveInfo
                    {
                        VolumeName = drive.VolumeName,
                        DriveLetter = drive.DriveLetter,
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
           return Drives;
        }
```

Comment: Check that your WCF service process has permissions to list the drives. GetDrives() requires SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode permission because it calls to native OS API.

Comment: @aloneguid I tried adding, `code` [assembly: SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.PermitOnly, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]`code` But received the error: Assembly generation failed -- SecurityAction type invalid on assembly

Comment: Try setting aspNetCompatibilityEnabled to true and impersonating a user.

Comment: Ive been doing all my testing in OOB so i tried it out of browser and now i'm receiving the error : An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost:6036/DirectService.svc'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services.

Comment: Actually, you can. Just add an answer to your own question and give that answer the check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i Finally Figure it out and the problem was that some drives have no Volume Name, Total Space or Free Space so it would just pukes on itself! Below is my working sample that is working flawlessly. :D

```
[OperationContract]
        public List<AllDriveInfo> ServerDriveInfo()
        {
            try
            {
                DriveInfo[] ComputerDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
                List<AllDriveInfo> ServerDrives = new List<AllDriveInfo>();
                foreach (DriveInfo drive in ComputerDrives)
                {
                    AllDriveInfo NewDrive = new AllDriveInfo();

                    NewDrive.DriveLetter = drive.Name.ToString();

                    try { NewDrive.VolumeName = drive.VolumeLabel.ToString(); }
                    catch (Exception ex) { NewDrive.VolumeName = " "; }

                    try { NewDrive.TotalSpace = Convert.ToDouble(drive.TotalSize) / Math.Pow(1024, 3); }
                    catch (Exception ex) { NewDrive.TotalSpace = 0; }

                    try { NewDrive.FreeSpace = Convert.ToDouble(drive.TotalFreeSpace) / Math.Pow(1024, 3); }
                    catch (Exception ex) { NewDrive.FreeSpace = 0; }


                    ServerDrives.Add(NewDrive);
                }
                return ServerDrives;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```